# Visualization problem with Octave in Coursera ML course

Tags: data-visualization, octave, visualization

During Coursera machine learning course by Andrew NG in the week 7 assignment(Ex 6), many may find this same problem to visualize data in octave.[Problem while executing ex6.m file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tpUO.jpg)

But I cannot find any solution because I should not touch the visualization code as previously instructed.
Thus I cannot find any solution and not getting the full marks at coding

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is the Octave version. Previously like this:

```
contour(X1, X2, vals, [0 0], 'Color', 'b');
```

But this is invalid in new versions. So instead you have to use one of these way [Conture function parameters(official)](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/contour.html)

So to solve the problem, you have to go to your visualBoundary.m file and change the counture function with
`contour(X1,X2,vals,'--');`
This will solve the visualization problem